# Error inflating class fragment in google map project

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-android-api-2

i developing a project that show Google Map on the Screen. i did each and every thing according to internet help and i also  follow the tutorial but i did not solve the problem  Here is my project..

MainActivity.java

```
package com.appscourt.jogging.track.map.health;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>       \
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appscourt.jogging.track.map.health"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.appscourt.jogging.track.map.health.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.appscourt.jogging.track.map.health.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="com.appscourt.jogging.track.map.health.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD9tu2CyVniM72vTAQcocWNlJEaACQ-3rs" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

logCat...

```
03-03 05:18:01.984: D/AndroidRuntime(1297): Shutting down VM
03-03 05:18:01.984: W/dalvikvm(1297): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appscourt.jogging.track.map.health/com.appscourt.jogging.track.map.health.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.appscourt.jogging.track.map.health.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     ... 11 more
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4242000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.ex(Unknown Source)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4745)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
03-03 05:18:02.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1297):     ... 21 more
```

Any one help me ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CarLiveTrackingMapScreen" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/tracking_screen_map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tracking_screen_header_rl"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Class File **You should exteds FragmentActivity**

```
public class LiveTrackingActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.live_tracking_activity);
    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.tracking_screen_map);
                myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();
                myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                myMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                myMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
                myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Add this code in your XML file

```
<uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" >
        </uses-library>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB6krIcZoYtN73-l8ijuwkbCw-yhLfp7DY" />
```

Feel free to ask if you have any query.

Answer (score 1):

The anwer is clear in your logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.
Expected 4242000 but found 0. 
You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Than add to your `AndroidManifest.xml` in your application element this line:

```
    <meta-data 
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
              android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Thanks to you, glad that my answer helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The error logs clearily said that you haven't added google play service version in your manifest file within < application> < /application> tag. So you should add it

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

So you have to add something like this way:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="com.appscourt.jogging.track.map.health.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Goolge API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyD9tu2CyVniM72vTAQcocWNlJEaACQ-3rs" />

   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```